# How to pipe gdb's full stack trace to a file?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb, stack-trace

I'm trying to get a stack trace as my service got into a deadlock. 
I'm using

```
gdb <binary> core.dump
gdb> set logging on
gdb> thread apply all bt full
... Here now i have to keep pressing ENTER till i get to end of all the thread trace. It takes around 5 mins for me to get all these traces?
```

Any trick to get the stack trace of all the threads to pipe to a file in a single command?

Comment: Can you put your commands in a file and then execute gdb with `--batch --command=FILE`?

Comment: You can also `set pagination off` before printing stack traces.

Comment: @ks1322 `set pagination off` is the right answer. Could you make it into an answer, so it gets proper upvotes and hopefully gets accepted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should turn off pagination for long outputs like this:

```
$ gdb <binary> core.dump
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) set pagination off
(gdb) thread apply all bt full
```

See gdb FAQ and documentation:

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_disable_the_.22Type_.3Creturn.3E_to_continue.2C_or_q_.3Creturn.3E_to_quit.22_pagination_prompt_in_GDB.3F
- https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html